# How can I decide on what font to use for each character in a string?

Tags: python, unicode, fonts, python-imaging-library

I am writing a Discord bot that greets new users with images (with their names written on them) using [Pillow](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/). And people often tend to use foreign Unicode characters in their names (or names in different languages such as Chinese, Japanese etc.) that my font doesn't support. They look as blank boxes. Examples:

- 你好
- | |ƶลƒҡเεŁ| |
- G̷̈̐e̸̾̾n̶͛̊e̴̊͗r̴̾́a̴͆̑t̸̿̌o̶̽̃r̶̈́̔Z̶̈́̑a̸̋̀l̸͋͝g̵̀̓

I've tried several fonts and learned that I can't just use a single font that supports all of this. Then I've come across [Google Noto](https://www.google.com/get/noto/) and apparently their font family supports all kinds of languages.

So here's my plan:

- Check every character in a string and see if the main font supports it

  - If yes, just draw the character
  - If no, find a different font that supports it, then draw it.

There are several issues with this:

- I shouldn't iterate over all of the fonts for each character and check if one of them supports it. It'll be really bad performance-wise.
- I don't know how I would draw each character and keep them look organized. I assume there will be a noticeable size and style difference between each font.

So far I've found the [fontTools library](https://pypi.org/project/fonttools/) that will let me check if a font supports a character or not, but I don't know how I should proceed from this point. I'm curious about;

- How almost every website supports and handles these texts?
- How would I achieve my goal using Pillow in Python?

Some help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Regarding _"I shouldn't iterate over all of the fonts and check if one of them supports it. **It'll be really bad performance-wise**."_, do you know this to be true? Once you have identified the font for one character, aren't the chances pretty good that it will also support the next character as well? So you will only be doing that font iteration test when a change in font is needed, right? If so, there may not be a performance problem with your approach at all.

Comment: Another approach might be to map code point ranges to different fonts so that you didn't need to do any iteration at all: if the Unicode code point for the current character is `x`, use the font mapped to that code point `x`. The article [Regular Expressions for Japanese Text](http://www.localizingjapan.com/blog/2012/01/20/regular-expressions-for-japanese-text/) may help to clarify this approach for code points for Japanese characters..

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar problem. I had to analyze all fonts I use and create a database of fonts and characters.

Simple request to this DB allows you to detect all required fonts.